# Error saving id's in select boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I want so save Id's from select boxes but is not saving the first and second option

Here is my tables:

```
|Invoice_Cias|
  |id|   |name|
    1     ABC
    2     DEF
    3     GHI
    4     JKL

|Invoices|
  |id|   |invoice_cia_id|
    1         1
    2         2
    3         3
    4         4
```

Here is the controller

```
class InvoiceController < ApplicationController   

  def new_invoice
     @cias = InvoiceCia.find(:all,:conditions=>['id IN (1,2)'])
     @cias2 = InvoiceCia.find(:all,:conditions=>['id NOT IN (1,2)'])
     @invoice = Invoice.new 
  end

  def create
     @invoice = Invoice.new(params[:invoice])
  end

end
```

Here is the view:
    <% form_for @invoice, :url => {:controller=>"invoice",:action=>'create'},:html=>{:id=>"new_client_form"} 
    
      <%= options_for_select(@cias.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id]})+"OTROS" %>

```
<p><div id="info1" style="display:none;">
    Others CIAS:
    <%= f.select :invoice_cia_id ,options_for_select(@cias2.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id]} )  %>
   </div>
   <div id="info2" style="display:none;"></div>
</p>
```

Here is the demo

```
http://jsfiddle.net/HgqNf/42/
```

The problem is when I select the first or second option "ABC"=1 or "DEF"=2 is always saving id=3

Is working fine when I don't select the first and second option and I want to save id=1 or id=2

Please somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

From your controller

```
   @cias2 = InvoiceCia.find(:all,:conditions=>['id NOT IN (1,2)'])
```

and you promote options to select from this object

```
   <%= f.select :invoice_cia_id ,options_for_select(@cias2.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id]} )  %>
```

and this object doesn't contain elements with id 1 or 2 as your condition in controller say.